# Open CV: Acces pixels of grayscale image

Tags: c++, opencv

I know this question can be wired for experts, but I want to access pixels of grayscale image in openCV. I am using the following code:

```
cv::Mat img1 = cv::imread("bauckhage.jpg", CV_LOAD_IMAGE_GRAYSCALE);
```

Now if I want to print any pixel(say at position 255,255) using `img1.at<float>(255,255)` I get `0`, which is not actually black pixel. I thought the image has been read as 2d Matrix.

Actually I want to do some calculation on each pixel, for that I need to access each pixel explicitly.

Any help or suggestion will be appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You will have to do this

```
   int x = (int)(img.at<uchar>(j,i))
```

This is because of the way the image is stored and the way `img.at` works. Grayscale image is stored in CV_8UC1 format and hence it is basically an array of `uchar` type. So the return value is a `uchar` which you typecast into an `int` to operate on it as ints.

Also, this is similar to your questions:
[accessing pixel value of gray scale image in OpenCV](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17919399/accessing-pixel-value-of-gray-scale-image-in-opencv)

Comment: It works, can I set values in this way too? I mean what if I want to set some value for pixel img.at<uchar>(j,i)?

Comment: just assign it: `img.at<uchar>(j,i) = 19;`

Answer (score 1):

float is the wrong type here.

if you read an image like this:

```
cv::Mat img1 = cv::imread("bauckhage.jpg", CV_LOAD_IMAGE_GRAYSCALE);
```

then it's type will be CV_8U, (uchar, a single grayscale byte per pixel). so, to access it:

```
uchar &pixel = img1.at<uchar>(row,col);
```

Comment: I get N% , i expect a decimal value.

Comment: @berak: sorry i did not understand, why are you using `&pixel`? Why don't you use just `uchar pixel`? I just want to know the benefit of using `&`.

Comment: so you can assign a new value later: `uchar &pixel = img1.at<uchar>(row,col); pixel = 23;` if you only want to 'get' the value, you don't need the reference